# How to enable palette in android studio?

Tags: android, mobile, android-palette

Palette in android studio is disabled , i dont know how to  fix it
[tHE FIRST screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i5Xw.png)

[the second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRfak.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "palette" for the AndroidManifest.xml file. That is only available for layout XML files. The AndroidManifest file is a special file, and it helps show things on the screen.